# JWT expired at 2020-05-13T07:50:39Z. Current time: 2020-05-16T21:29:41Z. I got this error after expiration of my jwt as log error says

Tags: spring-security, jwt

> My log error This is..

**Anything more if needed then please comment below. I think this is the issue i am getting for expiration time. But i want to know how to solve this type of issue if get in future. How to basically solve this issue. can i create jwt token everytime after time expiration?**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)

2020-05-16 21:29:23.574  INFO 5924 --- [           main] .j.a.SpringSecurityJwtExampleApplication : Starting SpringSecurityJwtExampleApplication on S-PC with PID 5924 (D:\eclipse-workspace\spring-security-jwt-example-master\target\classes started by S in D:\eclipse-workspace\spring-security-jwt-example-master)
2020-05-16 21:29:23.592  INFO 5924 --- [           main] .j.a.SpringSecurityJwtExampleApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-05-16 21:29:25.301  INFO 5924 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-05-16 21:29:25.461  INFO 5924 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 140ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-05-16 21:29:26.478  INFO 5924 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-16 21:29:27.421  INFO 5924 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 9002 (http)
2020-05-16 21:29:27.440  INFO 5924 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-16 21:29:27.441  INFO 5924 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
2020-05-16 21:29:27.721  INFO 5924 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-16 21:29:27.721  INFO 5924 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4002 ms
2020-05-16 21:29:28.065  INFO 5924 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-16 21:29:28.071  WARN 5924 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
2020-05-16 21:29:29.294  INFO 5924 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-16 21:29:29.438  INFO 5924 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-05-16 21:29:29.596  INFO 5924 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.9.Final}
2020-05-16 21:29:29.953  INFO 5924 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-05-16 21:29:30.264  INFO 5924 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-05-16 21:29:31.640  INFO 5924 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-05-16 21:29:31.689  INFO 5924 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-16 21:29:32.511  WARN 5924 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2020-05-16 21:29:32.959  INFO 5924 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@47eaf55c, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@994544, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@1d944fc0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2c16677c, com.javatechie.jwt.api.filter.JwtFilter@65859b44, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6f0c45f4, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3335afcf, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@2c0798bd, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7548e1fb, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@30cafd13, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@1f39269d]
2020-05-16 21:29:33.324  INFO 5924 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-05-16 21:29:34.331  INFO 5924 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 9002 (http) with context path ''
2020-05-16 21:29:34.335  INFO 5924 --- [           main] .j.a.SpringSecurityJwtExampleApplication : Started SpringSecurityJwtExampleApplication in 12.188 seconds (JVM running for 13.014)
2020-05-16 21:29:40.858  INFO 5924 --- [nio-9002-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-16 21:29:40.859  INFO 5924 --- [nio-9002-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2020-05-16 21:29:40.880  INFO 5924 --- [nio-9002-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 21 ms
2020-05-16 21:29:41.080 ERROR 5924 --- [nio-9002-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException: JWT expired at 2020-05-13T07:50:39Z. Current time: 2020-05-16T21:29:41Z, a difference of 308342064 milliseconds.  Allowed clock skew: 0 milliseconds.
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:385) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parse(DefaultJwtParser.java:481) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.parseClaimsJws(DefaultJwtParser.java:541) ~[jjwt-0.9.1.jar:0.9.1]
    at com.javatechie.jwt.api.util.JwtUtil.extractAllClaims(JwtUtil.java:32) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.javatechie.jwt.api.util.JwtUtil.extractClaim(JwtUtil.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.javatechie.jwt.api.util.JwtUtil.extractUsername(JwtUtil.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.javatechie.jwt.api.filter.JwtFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtFilter.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) ~[spring-security-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1591) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.29.jar:9.0.29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
```

> This is my JwtUtil class. I have created a time limit of expiration of 10 hours.

```
package com.sushovan.jwt.security.jwtutil;

//import java.security.Signature;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;

@Service
public class MyJwtUtil {

    private String secret = "sushovan";

    public <T> T extractClaims(String token, Function<Claims,T> claimResolver) {

        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);

        return claimResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    private Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    public String extractUserName(String token) {
        return extractClaims(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Date extractexpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaims(token, Claims::getExpiration);

    }

    private Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractexpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(String username) {
        Map<String,Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
        return createToken(claims, username);
    }

    private String createToken(Map<String, Object> claims, String subject) {
        return Jwts.builder().setClaims(claims).setSubject(subject).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 10))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret).compact();
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUserName(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }

}
```

Comment: One way to handle the user experience issue of JWT expiration is to use something called _refresh_ tokens.  You may start by searching for that term.

Comment: ok thank you  Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: did you find a solution? I'm not quite sure how to implement refresh tokens in my app